# ¿Como reutilizar una misma ventana modal,pero con un titulo o encabezado diferente?

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap

Estoy implementando varias ventanas modales mediante Bootstrap. Una para cada cosa diferente.He hecho la prueba para cargar diferentes datos en una misma ventana modal.

Explico....

Tengo una para recoger usuarios favoritos,otra para usuarios seguidores y otra para usuarios a los que sigo.

He hecho la prueba para cuando presiono el botón indicado ya sea para cualquiera de esos datos que quiero,me abran el mismo modal,pero con la diferencia de que me traen datos según el botón que presiono,ya sea favoritos,seguidores y siguiendo.Todo marcha muy bien.

Esos datos los traigo de la BD a través de ajax(Jquery) y PHP.

¿Cual es el problema?

El problema esta en el titulo que quiero para diferentes ocasiones.

¿Como hago aparecer un titulo diferente para cada tipos de datos que traigo.?

Ejemplo:

---

```
                              Usuarios favoritos.
```

---

---

```
                            Usuarios a los que sigo.
```

---

---

```
                            Usuarios que me siguen.
```

---

Quizás puedan entender lo que quiero decir.

Comment: No esta duplicada!!!!!!!!Cuando hice la primera era solo para el titulo diferente y la segunda era para hacer parecer elementos HTML,como textbox. El código que he adquirido es diferente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado algo en la misma pagina de Bootstrap

```js
  

  $(document).ready(function(){

$('#multi_opt_user').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(recipient)
 
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>







<a href="#" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#multi_opt_user" data-whatever="Personas que me siguen." class="add_more" id="add_more_to">Seguidores</a>


<a href="#" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#multi_opt_user" data-whatever="Mis favoritos." id="makeagifttosomeone">
    <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
    <span class="sp_style">Favoritos</span>
  </a>










<!-- Modal multipropositos,tanto para agregar usuarios a  -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="multi_opt_user" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
         <i class="fi-heart"></i>
             <button id="pethatlimypro" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                
               

                        <div class="modal-body">
                           <div id="pocos"></div>
                                  </div>

                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                          </div>
                                              </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                       </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero [BootstrapDialog](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) *(mira a partir de los ejemplos; en lo personal me gusta por que no necesito crear una `div` o **contenedor** donde se colocara todo)*; lo usas de la siguiente manera

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Aquí el título de tu formulario',
    message: 'aqui cadena que forma/contene los tag html de tu formulario o datos a mostrar',
    closeByBackdrop: false,
    closeByKeyboard: true,
    closable: true,
    size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_LARGE, // Hay varias opciones
    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_INFO, // Hay varias opciones
    onshown: function (dialogRef) {
                dialogRef.getModal()).first().focus();
    },
    buttons: [
            {
                label: 'Guardar',
                action: function (dialogRef) {
                                // Todo tu mágia a realizar
                                dialogRef.close(); // Se indica cerrar la ventana
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Cancelar/Cerrar', // Según sea requieras 
                action: function (dialogRef) {
                                dialogRef.close(); // Se indica cerrar la ventana
                }
            } /* Puedes agregar botones como necesites*/
    ]
});
```

ejemplo de una implementación; asumo ya obtienes tu html a mostrar y título definico

```
function mostrarMsgDialogo(elTitulo, elMensaje) {

   BootstrapDialog.show({
      title: elTitulo,
      message: elMensaje,
      /* Todo lo demás */
   });

}
```

ejemplo de uso:

```
<!-- todo lo necesario antes -->

mostrarMsgDialogo('Agregar', 'contenido html/texto');
<!-- otro -->
mostrarMsgDialogo('Nuevo', 'contenido html/texto');
<!-- otro -->
mostrarMsgDialogo('Modificar', 'contenido html/texto');
<!-- otro -->
mostrarMsgDialogo('Editar', 'contenido html/texto');

<!-- todo lo necesario despues -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Bastante sencillo, solo agregale un id al titulo

```
<h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal Header</h4>
```

Y crear una funcion para llamarlo con el titulo  que quieras poner

```
function mostrarModal(titulo) {
  $("#modalTitle").html(titulo);
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
}
```

Aqui el ejemplo completo:

```js
function mostrarModal(titulo) {
  $("#modalTitle").html(titulo);
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<button type="button" onclick="mostrarModal('Habia un pajaro chiquito')">modal titulo 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="mostrarModal('tengo sed')">modal titulo 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="mostrarModal('algo mas')">modal titulo 3</button>
```

Comment: No utilizo eventos en los botones,osea "onclick".

Comment: Amigo acaso no se puede poner en otro lugar el evento onclick,porque no lo estoy implementando.hago el llamado con ajax utilizando el id del enlace o boton.

Comment: el onclick era solo para levantar el modal para el ejemplo de uso sino no podria mostrarlo, cuando obtengas los datos con ajax puedes cambiarlo seteando `$("#modalTitle").html('lo que quieras poner de titulo');` la segunda linea `$("#myModal").modal("show");` hace que sea visible el modal

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando un id en el tag del título:
$("#titulo_dinamico").html(titulo_que_quieras)

**Tu tienes:**

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="titulo_dinamico">Aquí iría el título que quieres</h4>
        ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Cuando obtengas tu data por ajax, puedes agregarle un valor mas 'título'.
data.datos  = tu_data
data.titulo =  el_título
o colocarlo manualmente.